# How to receive value back from a stored procedure in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have table as follows

```
emp_id, emp_name, emp_address, emp_salary, emp_rating
```

I would like to get all the above rows ... I have written stored procedure as follows:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[fetch_empdata]
@empid int
AS
SELECT * 
FROM emptable
WHERE emp_id = @empid;
```

```
string connection = "Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbase + ";User ID=" + userid + ";Password=" + password;

conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand(storedprocedure, conn);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empid", empid));

rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Can anyone pls help me what are the commands to receive data from emp table? I would like to get all the columns corresponding to empid given in program.

Comment: The easiest solution is to use Entity Framework.  Is that an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rdr` to read the returned data. Immediately after `rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()` add:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    var firstName = rdr["firstName"];
    var lastName = rdr["lastName"];
    var employeeId = rdr["empId"];
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the reader as well. Might want to wrap it in a using block.

Comment: I agree, although the `using` is outside the scope of the code s/he provided.

Answer (score 0):

you have already got those in to your `rdr` object

```
           while(rdr.Read())
            {
            //  var something=  rdr[0] you can access columns here
            }
```

and your code should give procedure name ,

> SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("fetch_empdata", conn);

Answer (score 0):

```
rdr["NameOfColumn"]
rdr["NameOfColumn2"]
...
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!